# svn usage advice

Tags: svn

The probjem is that I have two sets of bugs top fix on the project. One to deploy in 5 days, and one to deploy in 10 days.

I am going to solve all the bugs before the fifth day but I do not want to deploy the last 5 before the release date (in 10 days).

How can I work on two separate codes and the merge all the modification?
Is it possible?

Do I have to create a branch?

Comment: You could branch for each bug at the same time, resolve potential conflicts when merging them back, or, branch out for the first, merge back and then branch out for the second.  There may be other ways of approaching this too.  Was this the question about?  Am I missing something?

Comment: tortoiseGit is great.

Comment: I need a step-by-step adice to solve the problem

Comment: unwillingness to deploy two fixes instead of one indicates architecture / management issues rather than those of version control

Comment: The DVCS comment is bad because the question is about process/procedures not technical issues with the tooling - it may well be that for a given process dvcs will help but it doesn't actually address the question - its like answering "how do I find a better route to drive to work" with "buy a new car". Process first, tooling *if necessary* second.

Comment: @gnat Aye, it does sound a bit weird ... if it's truly a bug and not a feature request then it should be deployed ASAP, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branching. Separate Branch for each bug (or batch of bug fixes), then you have complete control on when you merge back (ie release) the fixes. The book http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ is pretty good - work through that, or I'm sure there are lots of tutorials online.